# Overlap views in horizontal LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

I need to design a layout with five `ImageViews` in horizontal orientation.

I can reach my idea with a basic `LinearLayout`, but I want a design pattern like the following image:

[image]

**Note: All `ImageViews` are in oval design.**

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

you can overlap items in a `LinearLayout` using negative margins, but they won't stack in that order.

you could use a `RelativeLayout` instead. you'd lay out the items from outside to inside to achieve the desired stacking order.

here's an example with a fixed width:

```
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="150dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
    <ImageView 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
    <ImageView 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="25dp" />
    <ImageView 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="25dp" />
    <ImageView 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

if you don't have a fixed-width container, you'll have to calculate the margins in code with this approach.

of course, if you don't have a fixed width, you'll need code of some sort anyway as there's nothing built into android that's really meant for this sort of thing.

Comment: Could you please show me this design in `RelativeLayout`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `RelativeLayout` for this task. Here's an example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="-18dp" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/img1"
        android:layout_marginRight="-18dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/img4"
        android:layout_marginRight="-18dp"/>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/img3"
        android:layout_marginRight="-18dp" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/img2"
        android:layout_marginRight="-18dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Note that here, the last `ImageView` is the one that will be on top of all others.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for developing a Carousel kind of widgets. You can refer any Carousel implementation in android. Many are available, you can refer one here
https://code.google.com/p/carousel-layout-android/